# Centering the html5 code using css not working

Tags: css, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first website</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    div{
        margin:0 auto;
    }   
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
    <h1>My First Website</h1>
    <p> Welcome to my webiste! Here are some things I enjoy.</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Web Development</li>
        <li>Chess</li>
        <li>Reading</li>
        <li>Learning</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Favorite Quotes</h2>
    <blockquote>
        <p>Here is a favorite quote of mine...</p><br>
        <p> ...and another"</p>   
    </blockquote>
    </div>
</body>
```

why isnt this working? I want to have everything in the div to be at the center of the page, currently it is aligned to the left. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Beacuse the div is 100% wide by default...put a width (or max-width) on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set fixed width as by default you div is `100%` width and it's centered, but you don't see it:

```
div {
   margin:0 auto;
   width: 900px; /* or 80% */
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/55Rzh/)